# Create NSURL But Show Only Link Text

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController to share a screenshot in my app. From my understanding, we can have a text field, an image, and a URL. What I would like to do is have one of the words in my text field be a clickable URL in itself. Something like,

"Check out my high score in **myGameName**!" where myGameName is a link to my game's website. Basically what I am going for is just like an html link

```
<a href="url">Link text</a>
```

where just the 'Link Text' is actually shown. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: This looks good for you [RichContentLabel](https://github.com/cyndibaby905/RichContentLabel)

Answer (score 1):

No, the text field/image/URL are all separate items, because some services don't support them "natively".

Answer (score 1):

check this library to make attributed label https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)